# TCP Raw Socket using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sockets, tcp

I need to create communicate between my digital multimeter (Keithley DMM6500) and Excel (VBA) using TCP Raw Socket. It is possible to find various examples but I did not found anything for this type:

```
socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

Correct me if I am wrong but in this case I need to set IP and TCP headers. Easy to do it in C but how to do it in VBA? Do you know any article which can help me? Or should I make "workaround" calling some Python script from VBA? Thanks for every help.

Comment: You could try for just python script direct that outputs to excel (xlwings etc)

Comment: Why do you need a RAW (`SOCK_RAW`) socket, instead of a normal TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`) socket? Aside from being harder to use in general, RAW sockets have pretty tight security restrictions on most platforms. What do you want to do with a RAW socket that you can't do with a normal TCP socket?

Comment: "TCP Raw Socket" is mentioned in datasheet. I'd use normal TCP if I could.